# How to substitute a string in a file with two columns?

Tags: bash

My file content looks like this: (two columns separated by "tab")

```
Others  ___
Archaea ___
Archaea_Euryarchaeota   ___
Archaea_Methanomicrobia_o_RCII  ___
Bacteria1       ___
Bacteria2       ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Holophagae;o__Holophagales;f__Holophagaceae;g__    g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;__;__       ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;f__;g__     g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Sva0725;o__Sva0725;f__;g__ g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__[Chloracidobacteria];o__;f__;g__   g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__iii1-8;o__SJA-36;f__;g__   g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__;g__        g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__EB1017;g__  g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__Microthrixaceae;g__ g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;__;__;__   ___
```

I am trying to do is:

When I find `g__` in the second column, then I need to replace it with the last found word (after p__ or c__ or o__ or f__ or g__) in the first column. For instance in the line

```
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__Microthrixaceae;g__ g__
```

`g__` in second column should be replaced with `Microthrixaceae`.

Similarly, for the instance when `___` is found then replace with the last found word (after p__ or c__ or o__ or f__ or g__) in the first column. I would really appreciate your suggestions.Thanks!

The output should look like this:

```
Others  ___
Archaea ___
Archaea_Euryarchaeota   ___
Archaea_Methanomicrobia_o_RCII  ___
Bacteria1       ___
Bacteria2       ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Holophagae;o__Holophagales;f__Holophagaceae;g__ Holophagaceae    
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;__;__       Solibacterales
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;f__;g__     Solibacterales
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Sva0725;o__Sva0725;f__;g__ Sva0725
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__[Chloracidobacteria];o__;f__;g__   Chloracidobacteria
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__iii1-8;o__SJA-36;f__;g__   SJA-36
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__;g__        Acidimicrobiales
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__EB1017;g__  EB1017
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__Microthrixaceae;g__ Microthrixaceae
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;__;__;__   Actinobacteria
```

Comment: But `Microthrixaceae` is not the first word in the left column.

Comment: I mean, the first word after "f__ or o__ or c__ or p__ or g__". Is it clear now? Thanks

Comment: Can you update the Q with the full output for your input sample? That'd be more helpful

Comment: `Microthrixaceae` is also not the first word in the left column after "f__ or o__ or c__ or p__ or g__".

Comment: I have updated my question on how the output should be. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you mean "the last word in the first column", not "the first found word in the first column". Yes?

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks :)

Comment: Why does the 8th record (`Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;__;__       ___`) get updated eventho there is no `g___` in the second field?

Comment: the same result, that is the last word from the first column, so "Solibacterales".

Comment: So _When I find `g__` in the second column, then I need to replace it_ has no value?

Comment: So this becomes: "When I find `g__` or `___` in the second column, replace it with the last word found after (p__ or c__ or o__ or f__ or g__) in the first column." Right? What should happen if there are no words after (p__ or c__ or o__ or f__ or g__) in the first column? The line should be ignored? `SJA-36` is a word? What is a word? Why is it `Chloracidobacteria` and not `[Chloracidobacteria]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` or `perl` or even `sed` are definitely better choices here than pure `bash`. Here's a `perl` solution:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?)([a-z]__\[?)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\])?(;[a-z]?__)*(\t)([g_]__)/$1$2$3$4$5\t$3/' yourfilename
```

For some explanation on why this works, mouseover the highlighted regular expression string here: https://regex101.com/r/tLpMCG/1

(Note that the regular expression there is very slightly different than in this answer because here I used `perl`, but there I was forced to use `php`, and I had difficulty pasting in the tabs.)

Comment: Thanks! but it does only for "g__" . Can you please update for both "g__" and "___". Thanks

Comment: Sure. I just need to change the last `g__` to `[g_]__`.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't "g__|___" give the same result as "[g_]__"?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, `g__|___` would give the same result as `[g_]__`.

Answer (score 0):

One in GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F"[\t;]" '
BEGIN {
    p="^[pcofg]_+"
}
{
    for(i=NF-1;i>=1;i--)
        if($i~p "[^_$]") {
            b=$i
            sub(p,"",b)
            print gensub(/[^;\t]+$/,b,1,$0)
            next
        }
}1' file
```

Output:

```
Others  ___
Archaea ___
Archaea_Euryarchaeota   ___
Archaea_Methanomicrobia_o_RCII  ___
Bacteria1       ___
Bacteria2       ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Holophagae;o__Holophagales;f__Holophagaceae;g__    Holophagaceae
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;__;__       Solibacterales
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;f__;g__     Solibacterales
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Sva0725;o__Sva0725;f__;g__ Sva0725
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__[Chloracidobacteria];o__;f__;g__   [Chloracidobacteria]
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__iii1-8;o__SJA-36;f__;g__   SJA-36
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__;g__        Acidimicrobiales
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__EB1017;g__  EB1017
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__Microthrixaceae;g__ Microthrixaceae
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;__;__;__   Actinobacteria
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^\t]*)((p|c|o|f)__[[]?([^];[:space:]]+))([^\t]*)\t(g|_)__/\1\2\5\t\4/'
```

Because regexes are greedy, this get's the last word after `(p|c|o|f)__` and substituted for the second column.

Tested with:

```
cat <<EOF | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '\t' |
Others  ___
Archaea ___
Archaea_Euryarchaeota   ___
Archaea_Methanomicrobia_o_RCII  ___
Bacteria1       ___
Bacteria2       ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Holophagae;o__Holophagales;f__Holophagaceae;g__    g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;__;__       ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;f__;g__     g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Sva0725;o__Sva0725;f__;g__ g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__[Chloracidobacteria];o__;f__;g__   g__
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__iii1-8;o__SJA-36;f__;g__   g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__;g__        g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__EB1017;g__  g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__Microthrixaceae;g__ g__
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;__;__;__   ___
EOF
sed -E 's/^([^\t]*)((p|c|o|f)__[[]?([^];[:space:]]+))([^\t]*)\t(g|_)__/\1\2\5\t\4/'
```

produces:

```
Others  ___
Archaea ___
Archaea_Euryarchaeota   ___
Archaea_Methanomicrobia_o_RCII  ___
Bacteria1   ___
Bacteria2   ___
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Holophagae;o__Holophagales;f__Holophagaceae;g__    Holophagaceae
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;__;__   Solibacterales
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Solibacteres;o__Solibacterales;f__;g__ Solibacterales
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__Sva0725;o__Sva0725;f__;g__ Sva0725
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__[Chloracidobacteria];o__;f__;g__   Chloracidobacteria
Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria;c__iii1-8;o__SJA-36;f__;g__   SJA-36
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__;g__    Acidimicrobiales
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__EB1017;g__  EB1017
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Acidimicrobiia;o__Acidimicrobiales;f__Microthrixaceae;g__ Microthrixaceae
Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria;c__Actinobacteria;__;__;__   Actinobacteria
```

Short explanation of `^([^\t]*)((p|c|o|f)__[[]?([^];[:space:]]+))([^\t]*)\t(g|_)__` regex:

- `^` - match beginning of the file
- `([^\t]*)` - match and remember everything in front of the `(p|c|o|f)__`. We match up until `\t`, cause we are interested in first field only
- `((p|c|o|f)__[[]?([^];[:space:]]+))`

  - `(p|c|o|f)__` - match teh initialial prefix
  - `[[]?` - optionally remove the `[` in front of it
  - `([^];[:space:]]+)` - you didn't define what word is - I match up until `;` or `]` or whitespace is encountered.
- `([^\t]*)` - match the rest of first field
- `\t` - the separator
- `(g|_)__` - match the second field